# If I am writing a C program for an embedded system that has linux running on it, how would the functions and libraries used in my program differ?

Tags: c, embedded-linux

I am trying to understand how our application writing process changes when we have linux on the microprocessor/microcontroller i.e an operating system running in it. As far as I can see we still have the same old stdio.h and void main in the applications I have seen so far. What is Linux doing in the background? How do we make linux run our application as soon as it has booted? What do we make Linux do in these programs? I mean we can still open and close files and write to LCDs regardles of Linux right?

In other words, how does a bare metal code differ from when we have Linux? I have read somewhere that we have a C library called libc. Can't we use libc even when we do not have linux running in the background?

Comment: We can also do SPI, I2C, and use othe peripherals on the micrcontroller without needing Linux. We can also do printf, scanf among others without Linux. So what does a linux do and how does it effect the C code? I mean, we do have things like sed, grep among others in Linux, why don't we call them instead of writing all C code?

Comment: Operating System provides you an interface between hardware and your application, that's what Linux do. But that does not mean you cannot access hardware directly, that's why you are able to access LCD library files. Without linux you cannot use `libc` because there will be no interface to run high level app like `gcc`. mC and mP only recognize `0`s and `1`s. When you burn/dump a `hex` file, you still need some interface to translate your `hex` into these `0`s and `1`s in correct format.

Comment: @quantum231 You may or may not have stdio.h on a microcontroller. It depends on what development toolchain you use. Some have a very simple stdio.h and similar. But your program is usually the only thing running, i.e. unless you write it yourself, you can't run multiple processes, no disk-file I/O, perhaps no drivers for various hardware

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You probably want to read up on Busybox, uclib and buildroot. They let you have the full power of the kernel, but still keep your "Linux Distro" under 500Kb.  Don't worry about "Linux running the the background", it's rarely a big source of overhead. You can use the 'realtime' levels in the kernel to keep other processes from running. Also look into the deadline scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

C distinguishes two modes "freestanding" and "hosted":

- In a freestanding environment you only have a very limited part of
  the standard headers available, most of the standard library may be
  missing. This would be the case if you run your program on "bare
  metal". Your particular platform *might* offer you other parts of
  the C library, or even completely different stuff.

  Only guaranteed are  "float.h",
  "iso646.h", "limits.h", "stdalign.h", "stdarg.h", "stdbool.h",
  "stddef.h", "stdint.h", and"stdnoreturn.h". So "stdio.h" might not be there.
- In a hosted environment you have everything from the C library that
  is guaranteed by the C standard. With linux underneath you should at least have that.
- If you run linux, usually you will even be more advantageous. Linux
  implements POSIX, so you will have even more functionallity in the C
  library available. Much parts of POSIX are optional, so what you have
  would again depend of your platform provider.